# How to cd into smb://user@100.100.100.100 from terminal?

Tags: bash, terminal, mount, smb

I am using ubuntu and gnome on my computer.

When I open up File Browser, on the left hand rail, I see conveniently a folder called "Work Server".  When I mouse over it, the following caption appears "smb://john@69.100.100.1".  If I click on that folder, then I can see the contents of that folder.  Everything is great.

So now when I open up a terminal/shell, I type in

```
cd smb://john@69.100.100.1
```

I get an error saying the directory doesn't exist.   How do I enter this directory via shell/terminal?

Answer (score 31):

The reason you can't `cd` in that share is because `cd` only works on local filesystems*, you have two ways of solving your problem here:

Use `smbclient` to browse the share:

```
smbclient -U john //69.100.100.1/SHARENAME
```

or `mount -t cifs` if you want to mount the share locally, note that the mount point must exist as a folder:

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o user=john,iocharset=utf8,noperm //69.100.100.1/SHARENAME ~/shares/SHARENAME
```

Make sure you adapt *SHARENAME* to match your environnement.

If your login is part of an Active Directory domain you may want to add its name to those commands, with the second one that would be:

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o user=YOURDOMAIN//john,iocharset=utf8,noperm //69.100.100.1/SHARENAME ~/shares/SHARENAME
```

*  The meaning of "local" here is not straightforward, just keep in mind you can't use normal tools before you *mount* remote FS locally.

Comment: am I supposed to replace USERNAME with the name of my current shell user?  And SHARENAME with the directory name i want to cd into?  When i tried I got the following error: `Connection to john@69.100.100.1 failed (Error NT_STATUS_BAD_NETWORK_NAME)`

Comment: yep, you have to specify an 'endpoint' ("SHARENAME") which is the name of the share you can see in your GUI file browser and adapt "USERNAME" (maybe even add your domain before that) to be able to mount the share.

Comment: smbmount is deprecated and not maintained any longer. mount.cifs (mount -t cifs) should be used instead of smbmount ([smbmount Linux man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/smbmount))

Comment: how does one do an anonymous access with cifs? Is it just a matter of setting `user=anonymous`?

Comment: Just don't use 'user' at all for guest access.

Comment: Nice broken thing. You can have access to a samba share with PCManFM-QT on user-level, but to have access on console, you need mount on sudo level. Good job Linux. Solid solutions are drivers on OS-level and not on App-level (as PCManFM). I never understand why a user cannot mount.

Answer (score 6):

Shamelessly borrowed from https://askubuntu.com/questions/101029/how-do-i-mount-a-cifs-share

terminal command is:

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o username=USERNAME,password=PASSWD //192.168.1.88/shares /mnt/share
```

note you may need to install cifs-utils

Comment: where is the sudo

Answer (score 1):

Since it looks like the remote share is already mounted, there's no need to mount it again (sure you can, but do you want to?). Instead you need to find where has it been mounted. Since you're using GNOME, the big chance is it was mounted as [gvfsd-fuse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GVfs). If you're impatient, just try to run this:

```bash
ls "/run/user/$(id -u)/gvfs"
```

and check if you can see the directory where the share has been mounted (you should see something like `smb-share:server=remote.server,share=remote-share-name`). If you do, then you're done. :-) (Note that `id -u` or `id --user` gets your effective user ID — an integer number. If you know it up-front, you can safely replace the parentheses expression with it).

If it failed, you can run `findmnt` and look for `gvfs` entries in `FSTYPE` column. It may look like this:

```
TARGET                                 SOURCE         FSTYPE          OPTIONS
…
│   └─/run/user/1000/gvfs              gvfsd-fuse     fuse.gvfsd-fuse rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000
…
```

If you see this, check (`ls`) the path in `TARGET` column, in that case it's `/run/users/1000/gvfs` — you should be able to see your already mounted share here.

Answer (score -1):

```
open 'smb://login:pass@ip/Folder'
```